# not getting the string from jquery post return array data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
{"status":1,"return":364}
```

I'm facing problem to getting status and return value in jquery. how I get the single value from this array.

Comment: This is not an array. Its an object :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the answer:

```
  var status = data["status"];//prints 1
```

Comment: You can also do `var status = data.status;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not an array but its an object.

If I am right, you want to get the value of status object. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: I have used data.status but it return: undefined

Comment: Why are you using $data ??? Just declare it as var data = {status: “hello”}

Comment: I'm getting this code as a response from php file as {"status":1,"return":364} how I can convert this to var data = {status: "1"} ??

Comment: php file response means I'm getting response from api